# What is a possible Eclipse supported refactoring for removing superclass dependency?

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, refactoring

I want to remove the intermediate dependency of class B by moving the code from B to C and inherit directly from A.

```
generic class A
  |
  ---modified generic class B
       |
       ---current class C
```

Is there any refactoring from Eclipse to support this?

Comment: Congratulations on that question: I often find that most Java developers still refactor code by moving text pieces, while the majority of refactorings can be done with tool support (and verification!) in Eclipse nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Refactoring > Pull up** on all the methods of `C`.

Move all fields and constructors from `C` to `B`.  Make sure C and B are in the same package.

**Delete** the class `C`.

**Rename** class `B` to `C`.

You have to move fields and constructors by hand, but otherwise this should be a fairly safe and painless refactoring.